# How to configure parallelism in Oracle 10g?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, parallel-processing

I have created a table with parallelism degree 2, however it doesn't seem like it's actually working.

Comment: You definitely need to provide more detail on *what* is not working. Ideally with some example code and table structures, configuration settings etc. With this meager piece of text, no one will be able to help you. Moreover, you should put more care into formulating the question regarding spelling. I fixed it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its appears the i should  get a full licensed version of oralcle

Answer (score 1):

Post your SQL.  You can add a parallel hint, something like:

```
select /*+ parallel(d, 2) */
from someTable d
where blah;
```

Note that you need to use any aliases you used in the query (d in this case).  Typically the driving table of the query is used here.  Use explain plan to see if it changes after adding this hint.